# Windows 8 Live Tile Update Scheduled.

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, live-tile

I would like to create a scheduled live tile update to update a tile whether the app is running or not.  I would like the schedule an update every 24 hours. What would be the best way to do this either to use Secondary Tile, Tile Notification or Background task? Code snippets will be preferred. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While the question I added a link to asks about JavaScript, the answer is for C#

Answer (score 0):

Ill go ahead with the msdn Link rather than code snippet. As it will be helpful for you if you go through the article.

Best way is to use a Periodic Update that is provided itself by Microsoft's Api.

[Periodic Updates WinJs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761476.aspx)

go through the link implement the code as they explain.